# Uncaught ReferenceError: postAcmgForm is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm creating a form, however, when I try to submit the form using onclick event, I get the following error `Uncaught ReferenceError: postAcmgForm is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick`

I did try including the  tag inside the `<head>` tag and before the `</body>` tag and still, it doesn't work. The path mentioned in the src element is correct.

Following is the code

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        .inline-div {
            float: left;
        }
    </style>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="../controller/formcontroller.js" /></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div id="leftDiv" class="inline-div col-md-3">
        <head>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        </head>

        <form action="../controller/acmg_controller.php"  method="POST" target="_blank">
        <!--<form method="POST">-->
            <div class="form-group">
                PMID: 
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="pmid" name="pmid">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                ACMG Category:
                <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="ACMG" name="ACMG">
                    <option value="FUNCTIONAL STUDY | 9">Functional Studies</option>
                    <option value="ALLELIC | 10">Patients / Allelic data</option>
                    <option value="CO-SEGREGATION | 11" option="11">Disease co-segregation</option>
                    <option value="DE NOVO | 12" option="12">De novo mutation</option>
                    <option value="CASE CONTROL | 13" option="13">Case-control studies</option>
                    <option value="PHENOTYPE | 14" option="14">Phenotype/family history</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                Evidence Supports:
                <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="Evidence" name="Evidence">
                    <option value="Supports Benignnes">Supports Benignness</option>
                    <option value="Supports Pathogenic">Supports Pathogenic</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="summary">Summary:</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="text" name="text" rows="8"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type = "hidden" name = "genevar" id = "genevar">
                <script>
                    var hashParams = window.location.hash.substr(1).split('&');
                    var temvarient = hashParams[1].split('=');
                    var variant = temvarient[1];
                    var hashParams_ = window.location.hash.substr(1).split('&');
                    var temgene = hashParams_[0].split('=');
                    var gene = temgene[1];
                    //document.write(gene+' '+variant);
                    document.getElementById('genevar').value = gene + ' ' + variant;
                </script>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">

                <input type = "hidden" name = "mutation" id = "mutation" >
                <script>
                    var hashParams = window.location.hash.substr(3).split('&');
                    var mutation = hashParams[2].split('=');
                    var mutationtype = mutation[1];
                    document.getElementById('mutation').value = mutationtype;
                </script>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type = "hidden" name = "vkey" id = "pvkey" >
                <script>
                    var hashParams = window.location.hash.substr(0).split('&');
                    var temVkey = hashParams[3].split('=');
                    var vkey = temVkey[1];
                    document.getElementById('pvkey').value = vkey;
                </script>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                </script>
                <input type = "hidden" name = "genevar"id = "genevar" >
                <script>
                    var hashParams = window.location.hash.substr(3).split('&');
                    var mutation = hashParams[2].split('=');
                    var mutationtype = mutation[1];
                    document.getElementById('mutation').value = mutationtype;
                </script>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="postAcmgForm(this,event);" name="submit">Submit</button>

        </form> 

    </div>

    <div id="rightDiv" class="inline-div col-md-9">
        <div id="pdfview">
            <iframe id="pdfv"
                    src="...."
                    height="750px" width="100%">

            </iframe>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

The JavaScript code in '/controller/formcontroller.js' is

```
function postAcmgForm(id,e){
    var ACMG = $("#ACMG").val();
    alert(ACMG);
    $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url : '../controller/acmg_controller.php',
                dataType : 'json',
                data: {
                    ACMG:ACMG
                },
                success : function(data){
                $.each( data, function( key, value ){
                    $("#"+key).html(value));
                    alert(key + ":" +value);

                });

                },
                error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                    console.log("parse error for searchString");

                }
            });
}
```

The code in 'acmg_controller.php' is:

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
$date= date('Y-m-d');

$result = $_POST['ACMG'];
$result_explode = explode('|', $result);
$data_array = array('ACMG Category' => $result_explode[0],
                    'ACMG ID' => $result_explode[1], 
                    'Evidence Support' => $_POST["Evidence"], 
                    'Summary' => $_POST["text"], 
                    'Source' => 'PubMed',                   
                    'Date'=> $date, 
                    'Source ID' => $_POST["pmid"],
                    'Vkey' => $_POST["vkey"], 
                    'Gene Variant' => $_POST["genevar"],
                    'Mutation Type' => $_POST["mutation"]                   );
```

Comment: Where is ACMG ?

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `language="JavaScript"` and don't replace it with anything. Your code looks good otherwise but the `language` attribute was never implemented in a standard way and was then deprecated.

Comment: I tried removing ```language="JavaScript"``` and it still gives the error

Comment: Did you check the network tab of the Dev Console to make sure your controller is loading? (I mean, it's obviously *not* loading.) Maybe `../` isn't the right path?